# Self-hosted Katana service implement impersonation on a SQL Server connection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, katana

We're self-hosting our web applications as Windows services using Owin/Katana. `HttpListener` accepts the incoming connections and hands them over to the Owin pipeline.

In order to achieve integrated authentication on the web front-end, the Windows services need to run as `NetworkSystem` or `LocalSystem` as these are the only accounts that can interrogate the domain controller and verify a user's credentials.

The Windows services also need to query a SQL Server database. However, neither `NetworkSystem` nor `LocalSystem` have sufficient permissions to connect to the SQL Server so we need to impersonate another domain account when connecting to the database.

To achieve this, we tried to simply implement our own `IDbConnection` that would impersonate another user on the call to `Open` and then revert that impersonation on `Dispose`, ending up with code like:

```
using (var conn = _connectionCreator.Create(_configuration.ConnectionString)) //this creates our own IDbConnection with impersonation built in
{
    using (var cmd = _commandCreator.Create("mysproc", CommandType.StoredProcedure))
    {
        conn.Open(); //here we switch to the user we're impersonating
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        //do the rest            
    }
} //call to Dispose here reverts the impersonation
```

The problem we've encountered is that the call below throws a class cast exception:

```
cmd.Connection = conn; //throws a cast exception
```

It turns out that under the hood if your `cmd` is of type `SqlCommand` it expects the `Connection` object to be of type `SqlConnection`.

We can't extend `SqlConnection` because it is `sealed`.

Has anyone come across this need to impersonate when querying SQL Server? And if so, how did you solve it (without switching to IIS for hosting)?

Comment: Can you not simply use a single username/password (defined in the connection string) to connect to the database?

Comment: Unfortunately not as neither LocalService nor NetworkService have sufficient privileges to actually establish a connection to the SqlServer, regardless of the user name/pw in the connection string.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [Stack DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else needs to know, we eventually solved this by implementing our own versions of both `IDbConnection` and `IDbCommand` that wrapped `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` respectively. Implementing both got around the cast exception and allowed us to add the impersonation code.

```
public class SqlImpersonatedConnection : DbConnection
{
    private readonly SqlConnection _connection; //SqlImpersonatedConnection calls into _connection, doing impersonation where required

    private readonly string _domain;
    private readonly string _username;
    private readonly string _password;
    private IImpersonationContext _impersonationContext;

    public SqlImpersonatedConnection(string connectionString, string domain, string username, string password)  
    {
        _domain = domain;
        _username = username;
        _password = password;

        _connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    //more stuff
 }



public class SqlImpersonatedCommand : DbCommand
{
    private readonly SqlCommand _command; //SqlImpersonatedCommand just calls into command

    public SqlImpersonatedCommand(string commandText)
    {
        _command = new SqlCommand(commandText);
    }
}
```